# nginx test failing with different configuration file

Tags: django, nginx, docker, gunicorn, supervisord

I am trying to test why my nginx is failing to load, so I am running the command:

```
nginx -c nginx.conf -t
```

And getting the output:

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/share/nginx/vehicles/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: configuration file /usr/share/nginx/vehicles/nginx.conf test failed
```

Which is weird, because it states a different configuration file then I provided.

My configuration file:

```
user www-data;
daemon off;

events {
}

http {
    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    #access_log /logs/nginx_access.log;
    #error_log /logs/nginx_error.log;

    #upstream vehicles_server {
    #    server unix:/tmp/server.sock
    #}

    server {
        listen 5001;
        server_name _;

        location / {
            proxy_pass unix:/server/server.sock;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding the error_logs but they didn't work as well.

I am running the nginx using supervisord in an ubuntu docker container with gunicorn and Django as the web server (although I think they are completely unrelated to the problem)

the file server.sock exists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried on my server the following

```
nginx -c nginx.conf
```

And got :

> nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/local/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such
>   file or directory)

Then I did :

```
nginx -c /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

And it worked, try with the full path to your nginx.conf and should work

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! the problem in my script was missing the http:// in the  url. (for anyone that stumbles across this in the future)

Comment: That didn't solve the problem, because "/usr/local/nginx/nginx.conf" indeed does not exist. So why is it looking at that location?!